# Syncing files to Amazon Drive regularly using Rclone

Tags: linux, sync, cron

I want to synchronize my files with [Amazon Drive](https://www.amazon.com/clouddrive/). I am using a Linux headless machine and thought about using [Rclone](http://rclone.org/) for that. I am using `rclone sync localdir remote:dir` command to sync files local→remote but this is a one time sync.

How can I schedule a periodic (say, once a day) synchronization? Is `cron` a good way? Or does `rclone` provide its own mechanism? Will it work when I am not logged to the machine (it's always on)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way that I do it is with a cronjob. If it only runs once a day, you shouldn't have a problem with two instances trying to run, but you could always use flock to prevent that just in case:

```
0 23 * * * flock -n /some/lockfile rclone sync localdir remote:dir
```

Cron works whenever the machine is on, the user does not have to be logged on. You might, however, want to know/see a log of that task running. You can get the output of cron from:

```
grep CRON /var/log/syslog
```

but an easier/more consistent way might be to log the entire activity to a file like so:

```
0 23 * * * flock -n /some/lockfile rclone sync localdir remote:dir >> /var/log/myjob.log 2>&1
```

which will log both stderr and stdout in case you ever wanted to check on the job.